# How to print string containing numbers right-aligned?

Tags: c++

I am looking for ways to print numbers into a file in one right-aligned column.

My input is in string.

Example:

```
string s = {1,2.5,2.55,3,1000,100,15000,20,1,0,3.8};
```

Wished output:

```
    1
  2.5
 2.55
    3
 1000
  100
15000
   20
    1
    0
  3.8
```

Comment: First of all, how much do you know about sorting, for example using [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)? Secondly, how much do you know about [input and output manipulators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) and how they can be used to "manipulate" output formatting?

Comment: Google "C++ sort" for a good solution. Try it, by which I mean, write code. If you run into problems with your code, then SO is a good place to ask for help (just read the help section on how to ask etc).

Comment: Also, while that one line of code you show might compile with a few warnings, it's most likely not what you want. It is unclear what you are actually asking.

Comment: So wait, do the numbers need to be sorted or just right-aligned?

Comment: I using ofstream << . But I need to sort it into right aligned column.

Comment: just right aligned

Comment: So, find the length of the longest string and pad all the others with the appropriate number of spaces. But before we can actually help you with that, you need to show us how you store your numbers. Perhaps some of the code you've already written. `string s = {1,...};` doesn't make much sense, that's not a string, it's an array of numbers, presumably floating point.

Comment: is any nbsp in c++?

Comment: also, have a look at c++ stream manipulators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find longest string:

```
        ofstream myfile;
        std::istringstream f("line1\nline2\nline3");
        std::string line;   
        std::string longest = "";
        while (std::getline(f, line)) {
                std::cout << line << std::endl;
                if(line.length() > longest.length()){
                longest = line;
                }
        }

myfile << << std::right << setw(longest.length()) << "Your Text";
```

This is my solution

Comment: "Try to use" is hardly a solution. Please expand on this answer.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebd09d893aa91913. You need to get the length of the longuest string to print. And it only works for strings.

Answer (score 4):

[`std::right`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left), [`std::setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [`std::numeric_limits<T>::max_digits10`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10) are the tools you need:

- `out << std::right` sets the `out` stream to be right aligned.
- `out << std::setw(x)` sets the width of `out` to be `x` characters.
- `std::numeric_limits<T>::max_digits10` returns the maximum number of digits needed to represent a value of type `T` in base 10.

#### Example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    const std::array<double, 5> data = { 1, 2.5, 2.55, 3, 1000 };
    for (auto x : data) {
        std::cout << std::right << std::setw(std::numeric_limits<decltype(x)>::max_digits10) << x << '\n';
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
            1
          2.5
         2.55
            3
         1000
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed36f81c333fa4ad).

Printing into a file through an `fstream` is done similarly.

Answer (score 1):

I would store your numbers as double, not as strings to start with. Use sttod to convert a string to a double.

Take a look at [cplusplus.com site](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) which uses the std::sort library.
To print them I would suggest using printf for basic output, or fprintf if you would to write it to a file.

```
double ds[] = {1,2.5,2.55,3,1000,100,15000,20,1,0,3.8};
int cds = _countof (ds);
std::vector<int> vds (ds, cds);
std::sort (vds.begin (), vds.end ());
for (int i = 1; i < cds; ++i)
  printf ("%09f\n", vds [i]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
vector<string> s = { "1", "2.5", "2.55", "3", "1000", "100", "15000", "20", "1", "0", "3.8" };
vector<double> d;
auto conv = [](const string &s)
{
    stringstream ss(s);
    double d;
    ss >> d;
    return d;
};

std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(d), conv);
std::sort(d.begin(), d.end());
std::ofstream file("1.txt", std::ios::out);
std::transform(d.begin(), d.end(), s.begin(), [](double val){return to_string(val);});
for(auto &str : s)
{
    auto str1 = str + "\n";
    file.write(str1.data(), str1.size());
}
```